# Необычное Горизонтальное меню

Tags: css, jquery, html5

Прошу вашей помощи с написанием не стандартного горизонтального  адаптивного меню. Где то на просторах интернета видел уже такую реализацию. В общем борюсь с такой задачей. Нужно сделать горизонтальное меню которое бы при не помещении ширины экрана уводило пункты меню в выпадающие и создавало кнопку при нажатии на которую выводило бы это выпадающие подменю только вся сложность что бы скрывало только те которые не поместились с правой стороны.

Comment: Что Вы уже сделали? Приложите код ваших попыток.

Comment: Покажи Вашу страницу как, примерно, она выглядит?